# How do I access Sinatra's Logger outside the Request Scope

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra

It seems that Sinatra's logger is only available inside request handlers (See https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra#logging), but what if I want to use a logger in other places, for example in helper methods or in the configure hook? Is the Sinatra logger available through other means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Scopes%20and%20Binding) give some examples on scope, but you can see the `logger` helper within methods defined in the `helper` block, as the helper block has Application scope. Within configure it's not available, but what I tend to do is set up my own logging anyway, within the rackup file as a constant or class instance variable, and then it's available within configure (and anywhere else). As an example for just a single application:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'logger'

configure do
  set :logging, nil
  logger = Logger.new STDOUT
  logger.level = Logger::INFO
  logger.datetime_format = '%a %d-%m-%Y %H%M '
  set :logger, logger
end

helpers do
  def check
    settings.logger.info "I'm inside a helper"
    # if you were using Sinatra's logger, you could just call
    # logger.info "I'm inside a helper"
    # and it would work, but only if you've not done the stuff above
    # in the configure block
  end
end

get "/" do
  check # this would work for the way above, or with the Sinatra logger
  "Hello, World!"
end

get "/another" do
  settings.logger.info "Using the settings helper this time" # this only works
  # when you've defined your own logger
  "Hello again"
end
```

---

An example as a class instance variable as a better "global":

```
class MyLogger
  def self.logger
    if @_logger.nil?
      @_logger = Logger.new STDOUT
      @_logger.level = Logger::INFO
      @_logger.datetime_format = '%a %d-%m-%Y %H%M '
    end
    @_logger
  end
end
```

and then use wherever needed:

```
configure do
  set :logging, nil
  logger = MyLogger.logger
  set :logger, logger
end
```

or in a class:

```
class AnotherClass

  def some_method
    MyLogger.logger.warn "I'm in some method"
  end
```

---

Sinatra also comes (since 1.3) with [a helper for logging](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Logging), and [here is a recipe](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/middleware/rack_commonlogger) for logging to STDOUT and a file that you may find useful too.

Comment: I'm still unable to log within other classes. My handlers create objects that then do most of the work and I'd like to log within those classes. Help?

Comment: That's great, thanks! To get it to work without creating a log object I had to append `self` to the method, but I'm definitely onto the right track now.

Comment: @lyonsinbeta Whoops, forgot the `self`, well spotted! Glad it was a help.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't quite work for me, so I came up with the following:

```
class AppLogger
  extend SingleForwardable

  def_delegators :logger, :info, :error, :warn, :level

  class << self
    def logger
      return @_logger if @_logger

      @_logger = Logger.new STDOUT
      @_logger.level = Logger::INFO
    end

    def suppress_logging
      logger.level = Logger::FATAL
    end
  end
end
```

`suppress_logging` is useful for keeping specs quiet.

In the app init:

```
set :logging, AppLogger.logger
```

From a request:

```
logger.info "Can't touch this."
```

From a class that does not have access to the `logger`:

```
AppLogger.info "You've got mail."
```

And, RSpec mock:

```
let( :logger ){ double 'logger' }

before do
  allow( AppLogger ).to receive( :logger ).and_return logger
  allow( logger ).to receive :error
end

specify 'logs error' do
  post '/raise/error'

  expect( logger ).to have_received( :error ).with 'An error has occured.'
end
```