# Sinatra logging outside request

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra

I believe I'm missing something with the way Sinatra does logging. I'd like to define a custom logger but also use it outside Sinatra's routes.

My app.rb looks like this:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'logger'

logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

configure do
  use Rack::CommonLogger, logger
end

get '/' do
  logger.info 'In request'
  'Hello, world!'
end

logger.info 'Outside request'
```

The config.ru like so:

```
require 'sinatra'
require_relative 'app'

configure do
  enable :logging
end

run Sinatra::Application
```

But when I run the application and curl the URL, I only see the log out during the request, not `logger.info 'Outside request'` when the application loads.

```
$ bundle exec rackup
I, [2015-06-22T23:09:32.789802 #6122]  INFO -- : Outside request
[2015-06-22 23:09:32] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-06-22 23:09:32] INFO  ruby 2.1.4 (2014-10-27) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-06-22 23:09:32] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=6122 port=9292
::1 - - [22/Jun/2015:23:09:48 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13 0.0059
::1 - - [22/Jun/2015:23:09:48 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13 0.0124
Hello, world!%
```

I know I'm missing something fundamental here, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Outside request is, as you state, outside of the request: when you make a request, that code will not be ran. This has nothing to do with the logger. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: If I understand Ruby correctly, the `logger.info 'Outside request'` should get executed when the file is loaded, but it never is (or it's output is swallowed).

Comment: In your output, the first line after the command to start contains the `Outside request` logger output. If anything it’s the `In request` line that is missing. Note that by defining `logger` as a variable you are hiding the [Sinatra `logger` method](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Logging) (which by default logs to the logger set up by the web server). Also [`CommonLogger` is something else](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.4/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb), I don’t think it’s relevant to your issue.

Comment: One more thing – how are you making requests to the app? Your output just shows the body of the response after the server output (with an extra `%`) almost like the output from `curl` without actually running `curl`.

Comment: @matt, the problem is I'm an idiot. How did I miss the output? This example is contrived, in the real example I'm not seeing the log output. I going to have to come up with a better example.

Comment: @matt sot he issue I'm running into is I don't see any output when I deploy it to Dokku (Heroku like PaaS). I also can't seem to reproduce it when I have RACK_ENV=production

Comment: Those methods are actually wrapped in a Server class right? As in `class Server < Sinatra::Base` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access Sinatra's Logger outside the Request Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463512/how-do-i-access-sinatras-logger-outside-the-request-scope)